# Show minus of two forms in the third forms disabled

Tags: javascript, forms, twitter-bootstrap, laravel-4, laravel-blade

Working on a code where in the forms Fritt Klor (minus) Total klor = bundet klor. So I want the user to input the values in the fritt klor and total klor and the form bundet klor beeing disabled just showing the result.

Thought about a way to do it in javascript, but not sure how to.

Here are the forms:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label  class="col-md-7 control-label">Fritt klor: </label>
    <div class="col-md-5" >
      {{ Form::text('M_Fritt_Klor', Input::old('M_Fritt_Klor'), array('class' => 'form-control' ))  }}  
    </div>
  </div>



  <div class="form-group">
    <label  class="col-md-7 control-label">Total Klor: </label>
        <div class="col-md-5">
            {{ Form::text('M_Total_Klor', Input::old('M_Total_Klor'), array('class' => 'form-control' )) }}  
        </div>
  </div>   

         <div class="form-group">
    <label  class="col-md-7 control-label">Bundet Klor: </label>
        <div class="col-md-5">
            {{ Form::text('M_Bundet_Klor', Input::old('M_Bundet_Klor'), array('class' => 'form-control' )) }}  
        </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You included tag twitter-bootstrap so I assume jQuery is available. Here is simple javascript code:

http://jsfiddle.net/eYj8B/14/

```
$(function() {
  var inputs = $('input[name="M_Fritt_Klor"],input[name="M_Total_Klor"]'),
      output = $('input[name="M_Bundet_Klor"]');
    function parse(value) {
        return parseFloat(value.replace(',','.'));
    }
    function format(value) {
        return Math.round(value * 100) / 100;
    }
  inputs.keyup(function() {
      var value = parse(inputs[0].value)+parse(inputs[1].value);
      if (!isNaN(value)) {
          output.val(format(value).toString().replace('.',','))
      }
  });
});
```

Comment: That worked great. But if i want to round the decimal til two as (,XX)? Now it's rounding it to closest integer. Thanks, appriciete it mate.

Comment: Just replace parseInt with parseFloat.

Comment: You are probably using comma as decimal separator. I've updated fiddle to handle this case.

Comment: Thanks, now I got another problem. Its showing the correct but how do I replace the result with comma  ? Now showing: 4.46 and I need 4,46.

Comment: I found that it only supports dot (.) in the two first forms. I would like to write decimal values in comma and get the result in comma.

Comment: Thanks! I have a small question, If I try to not addition but minus how can I round after the decimal to ,XX ? dropbox.com/s/jk30qr70z9hcqsk/30-03-2014%2017-10-41.png